# Create a numbered list within a textarea element in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a text area element, where on load it should display a "1. ". The user can then type a sentence and hit return. Upon return it should render a "2." in the next line. When a user is on a line that has no text and clicks backspace, it should delete the number and return the focus to the previous number point. To illustrate this: User is on line "2." -> They press backspace which removes the "2." bullet point. -> returns them to the last character of line "1."

So far i have figured out this much:

```
const React = require('react');

const TextArea = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      textAreaVal: '1. '
    };
  },

  editTextArea: function(value) {
    this.setState({
      textAreaVal: value
    });
  },

  render: function() {

    return (
      <div className={"container"}>
        <textarea autoFocus className={"proposal-textarea"} wrap="hard" defaultValue ={this.state.textAreaVal}
          onChange={this.editTextArea} />
      </div>
    );
  },
});

module.exports = TextArea;
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on the best way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is Reacts [`onKeyDown`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events) event.

Same way you have `onChange` set up, set up a function for `onKeyDown` that sends to `this.handleKeyDown(event)`.  Within that function, test `event.charCode` to determine which key was pressed (enter should be `13` and backspace should be `8`), and then apply the necessary actions as needed.

EDIT:  Moving my comment to the answer block;

To handle the incrementing number, simply add a secondary state element, `lineNumber`.  Initialize it to `1` at start.  Whenever you detect a keypress of Enter, increment `lineNumber` and append `"\n" + this.state.lineNumber + ". "` to your `textAreaVal`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byoigres/xbkgke8q/2/)

```
const { Component, PropTypes } =  React;

class NumberedTextArea extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
        this._onKeyDown = this._onKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        counter: 2,
      text: `1. `
    }
  }
  _onKeyDown(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode ===13) {
      console.log(this.refs.text.value);
      this.refs.text.value = `${this.refs.text.value}\n${this.state.counter++}. `;
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
  render() {
    const style = {
        height: 300,
      width: 200
    };

    return (
      <textarea ref="text" onKeyDown={this._onKeyDown} style={style}>
        {this.state.text}
      </textarea>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberedTextArea />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: But how do you put he values in a state object